# Error in BMI calculator

Tags: python

I am trying to calculator using classes in python. I tried to solve in this way:

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self,name,age,weight,height):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
      self.weight = float(weight)
      self.height = float(height)
  def get_bmi_result(self):
      bmi = (self.weight)/float((self.height*30.48)*(self.height*30.48))
      print bmi
      if bmi <= 18.5:
        return "underweight"
      elif bmi>18.5 and bmi<25:
           return "normal"
      elif bmi>30:
           return "obese"
  pass
```

when I call the constructor:`p = Person("hari", "25", "6", "30")` and `p.get_bmi_result`
it was returning `<bound method Person.get_bmi_result of <Person object at 0x00DAEED0>>`
 .
I entered weight in kilograms and height in foots and in the calculation I tried to convert foot to centimeters.

Comment: What does weight `6` and height `30` mean? What are those units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot to *call* your method:

```
p.get_bmi_result()
```

Note those `()` parenthesis. You only dereferenced the bound method object.

*With* the call, your code runs just fine:

```
>>> class Person(object):
...   def __init__(self,name,age,weight,height):
...       self.name = name
...       self.age = age
...       self.weight = float(weight)
...       self.height = float(height)
...   def get_bmi_result(self):
...       bmi = (self.weight)/float((self.height*30.48)*(self.height*30.48))
...       print bmi
...       if bmi <= 18.5:
...         return "underweight"
...       elif bmi>18.5 and bmi<25:
...            return "normal"
...       elif bmi>30:
...            return "obese"
... 
>>> p = Person("hari", "25", "6", "30")
>>> p.get_bmi_result()
7.17594027781e-06
'underweight'
```

Clearly your formula needs adjusting still, a BMI of 0.000007 is *radically* underweight for someone weighing 6 stone, even if only 30 inches(?) small.

Depending on what your weight and height unit sizes are, you may need to [consult the BMI formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index#International_variations) and adjust your method a little.

Comment: I would not call reporting a BMI of 7 * 10^-6 "working just fine". The unit conversions are very incorrect, and it's not even clear what units are expected for the input. It *seems like* OP is expecting weight in kilograms and height in feet (why mix systems like that?), but even then, it makes no sense for a person to be 6kg and 30 feet tall (parameters are in the wrong order?), and even *then*, height should be multiplied by .3048, not 30.48 (which gives feet -> cm, not feet -> m).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: right, I did not verify the formula; I focused on the call problem instead. Used *runs* instead of *works*..

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: and 30.48 squared is 61-ish, but that's still not jiving with the [metric or imperial formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index#International_variations)..

Comment: I wonder I did not even notice the way the parameters are passed thankyou@MartijnPieters